# Iterative Bisector Method for finding the minimum of a non - differentiable function

Tags: iteration

I would like to automate a process to find the minimum of a non-differentiable function, perhaps using a similar system as the bisection method but adapted to finding minima instead of roots. Any ideas or tips on how to implement this or what functions to use would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: example of function?

Comment: Can you claim the minimum is a global one? Or that a local minima is good enough?

Comment: A non-differentiable function could be very badly behaving. Look at the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. There exist no methods that can handle such functions.

Comment: Essentially i have a function which extracts an eigenvalue from a matrix and this eigenvalue is dependent on a parameter. I can plot the eigenvalue as a function of this parameter and see the minimum by eye but i get errors when using functions like findminimum because it cant differentiate it.

Comment: @KJohn when using these functions, are you using the list of eigenvalues you have created? If so, then it should be easy to find the minimum

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method "DifferentialEvolution" or "SimulatedAnnealing" in **NMinimize**

```
M = {{1, x, 2}, {-1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 5}};
NMinimize[Max[Abs[Eigenvalues[M]]], x, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution" ]

Plot[Max[Abs[Eigenvalues[M]]], {x, -10, 0}]
```

Comment: This did not work for my code, I will edit my post with my code included.

Comment: I tried to run your code but it hangs on **H2[]** calculations.